# Check if music playing in android media player API

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using this code below to play an audio file in android

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("fileSourceHere");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

I have a button on that program. When click on that button, it'll check if music playing. If music playing, it'll stop that. How can I check if music playing? I tried the code below but it didn't work

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
 mediaPlayer.pause();
}else{
 mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: You don't need `== true`. `isPlaying()` checks for you. Everything else seems correct.

Comment: Can you explain what happens? "it didn't work" doesn't say what did or did not happen.

Comment: music didn't stop. Nothing else happened.

Answer (score 13):

To check if Music playing by any other app. Use

```
AudioManager.isMusicActive();
```

And if you want to know about your app music.

Add Listener to listen

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

you can add a boolean variable to check isPlaying;

```
boolean isPlaying= false; //false by default
```

and when you `start mediaPlayer` at the very moment set `isPlaying=true` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("fileSourceHere");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();

if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
else
{
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("fileSourceHere");

If(mediaPlayer != Null){
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true)
{ 
mediaPlayer.pause();
}
else
{
 mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
else
{
//mediaPlayer is null
mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

I had almost the same problem. Android studio generates an error when you try for the first time because there is no music as datasource.  ;)