# Java How to Show then Hide (GONE) View-Android

Tags: java, android, visibility

I am developing an APP in Android Studio (cause I'm not a Java pro-just learning...) I am not sure if my code is not working-which it looks like it is not to me. Can anyone lend a hand?

I have a music file that when it plays I won't to show the progress bar-THEN hide it with visibility (GONE). Everything works just fine, except I cant' get the VISIBILITY to change if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying)...

Basically after the 10-seconds of audio plays the progress bar needs to change the view back to gone.

```
   final ProgressBar Pbar;
   Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

   final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
   R.raw.soundttt);
    Button playsound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_sound_ten);
    playsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    });
```

I have been trying for three days, have done my fair share of reading including the numerous threads on MediaPlayer.

[StackOverFlow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160089/check-if-music-playing-in-android-media-player-api)
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Above code will be executed immediately after media player has started playing. This condition will be false, as a result view's visibility is not impacted.

If you wan't to toggle the Visibility after 10 seconds, do it using Handler as follows:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         Pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
 },10000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew something wasn't working properly. It was my fault for not having a statement run after the if statements... Can I ask if there is also other ways to achieve handler?I just read up on handlers, and they basically process queues how we want them to.

Comment: @samlf3rd you mean, you want alternative to Handler?

Comment: I am just wondering if somewhere down the line if I ever run into an issue where handler wouldn't work and something else takes over where handler leaves off?

Comment: @samlf3rd If you are dealing with UI component you can either use Handler or `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){...})`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your time @Sagar! I can finally relax tonight knowing that the code works, and I am excited to learn more!